# importing text files within MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, text, emacs

I'm looking for this solution for an hour in the web and books but I can't find it anywhere.

I've made a MySQL script via Emacs, but I would like to implement it to create a database by importing or including the script (instead of copy-paste it into the terminal).

PS: I'm not looking for importing values to an existing database; I'm really looking to implement a script, like for example:

```
create database store;
create table user(
        ID integer not null auto_increment primary key,
        'FIRST NAME' varchar(20) not null,
        'LAST NAME' varchar(20) not null,
        AGE tinyint not null,
        LOCATION text not null);

-- inserting virtual users
insert into user('FIRST NAME', 'LAST NAME', AGE, LOCATION) values
        ('John', 'Thomas', 21, 'EN'),
        ('Richard', 'Randy', 51, 'US');
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

Save it to a file eg schema.sql and then run

```
mysql -u username -p < /path/to/schema.sql
```

With whatever hostname, authentication you normally use.

[Explained in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-batch-commands.html)

Comment: Thank you very much. It was that basic!

Answer (score 2):

```
I tried like this and its working fine for me .

webelitetest   --- Database name

courses.sql   --- Sql File name

c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -h localhost -u root -p webelitetest<C:/courses.sql
```